# Snapshot in Elasticsearch of a specific index failing on Node.js

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, coffeescript, elasticsearch-plugin

I try to create a snapshot of a single index using the indices parameter within the official node.js module, but I always end up with getting a complete snapshot of the cluster.

```
@es.snapshot.create( 
   { snapshot: "#{uid}", indices: index, repository: @config.esrepo, include_global_state: false }
   ( err, created ) -> 
      ...
      ...
)
```

The above coffeescript transiling to something like this:

```
_this.es.snapshot.create({
            snapshot: uid,
            indices: index,
            repository: _this.config.esrepo,
            include_global_state: false
          }, function(err, created) {
              .....
          });
```

Is this due to a bug or missing feature in the es client? The indices parameter is being described within the API, but no within the JS client API ...?

Comment: What values do you have in `index` and `@config.esrepo`?

Comment: what error do you get? what do ES logs say?

Comment: @config.esrepo is the name of the Snapshotrepository, which - in this case - is an AWS S3 based repo. ES does not throw an error, but it always snapshots ALL indices, despite having explicitly defined only one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Simple error - shame on me. The `indices` parameter has to be part of the `body`, which simply was missing in my request.